# Insert data into JList without deleting another

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am adding data that I capture from a jTextField into a jList. Whenever I press a jButton, the jList must be updated with the jTextField data. However, whenever I do this, the previous data is erased, that is, my list always has 1 element. The code is:

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
 list.addElement(jTextField1.getText());
 jList1.setModel(list);
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();` each time creates a brand new `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, whenever I do this, the previous data is erased,

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
```

Don't create a new DefaultListModel.

You can either:

1. Create an instance of the `DefaultListModel` when you create the JList (and then reference it in your code above), or
2. In your curret code you get the current `DefaultListModel` from the `JList` using the `getModel()` method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` example does exactly what you want.